# Parse Server error: unauthorized and Python connection issues

Tags: python, heroku, parse-server

I just set up my first Parse test server on Heroku, and am having 2 main issues:

**Issue 1)** https:// [MY SERVER URL] /parse is returning `{error: 'unauthorized'}`. I've tried using Postman to authenticate using the headers

```
   "X-Parse-Application-Id": xxx
   "X-Parse-Master-Key": yyy
```

where xxx and yyy are my AppID and MasterKey.

**Issue 2)** I am not able to connect to the API using Python. I AM able to submit successful requests from the Parse dashboard itself, and also using cURL:

`curl -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxx" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: undefined" https://[MY SERVER URL]/parse/classes/Customer` (this works)

But when I use the following code (as it states in the Parse API documentation), I am not getting getting an

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

This doesn't surprise me, since here is the Python script I'm using to connect:

```
import json,http

connection = http.client.HTTPConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET',
        '/1/classes/Customer/', '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "myAppID",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "undefined"
     })

result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
```

In particular, it's the connection.getresponse() function call that is returning the error.

I know this doesn't look right since I don't see where I'm supposed to specify my server URL, and I have a suspicion these two issues are interconnected. Can someone help me shed some light on what's going on? I've read through the PARSE REST documentation pretty thoroughly (https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/) and followed along using the same structure for the requests.

Comment: Did  solved it ? I'm having the very same problem

Comment: I have not unfortunately.